# Search API views is displaying empty pages

Tags: search, 9

My search page is displaying results. The pager is displaying. But the first 15 pages display no results and then on the 16th page, I can see the content.

I have deleted all the data from the index, and re-index the data again but no effect. Can anyone tell me why the first 15 pages are empty? and how can I fix it?

When I print the results in `hook_search_api_results_alter`, it is something like this

```
"1wucgy--entity:node/2011:nl" => Drupal\search_api\Item\Item
```

When I go to the page where some content is displaying, The results are like this.
[image]

So the nodes with `1wucgy--` are not displaying and the nodes without that hash are displaying.

So on the first 15 pages, all the nodes are prefixed with `1wucgy--` and that is why those pages are empty.

Is there any way to exclude these types of nodes from the results?

Comment: Basically this means items returned from Solr don't exist in the local Drupal database and cannot be loaded. You need to filter items by site hash / site id if you are indexing multiple sources.

Comment: How can I filter them?